# ElectronJS: How can I change the Electron homepage option when right-clicking the app's icon on the taskbar?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I'm creating an app with Electron. The app is works fine, but when I right-click[1] the app's icon on the taskbar; it shows an Electron option to open the Electron homepage[2].

[[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDdIw.png)
[[2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPVNC.png)

So how can I change that option to open my own app?

I can't find anything about that in the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood what you think is the "Electron homepage", because what you see is not the homepage, but a new instance of `electron.exe` that is not running any main script. The list you are referring to is called the `JumpList`, and above the options to pin the app to the taskbar, there will always be the default option of opening a new app window (Electron in this case). This function can not be changed or removed.

To verify it's an empty Electron instance, you can run `node_modules/electron/dist/electron.exe` or `npm run electron` (without any arguments to electron.) in your project.

When you have your app built into a packaged executable using a tool like [Electron Forge](https://www.electronforge.io/) or [Electron Builder](https://www.electron.build/), this executable will then have the name of your app instead of "Electron" and the function in the `JumpList` will consequently open a new instance of your app instead of an empty Electron container. So to "change" the default function, you would need to use a tool to package your Electron executable.

Here is an image of how this looks like for an app fresh out of `yarn create electron-app my-fancy-app`, running `yarn package` in the project and executing `.\out\my-fancy-app-win32-x64\my-fancy-app.exe`:

[Windows JumpList in packaged Electron app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKfKl.png)

To change the name of your executable when built by Electron Forge or Electron Builder, you can change the `productName` property in the `package.json` of your project:

```json
{
  "name": "my-fancy-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "productName": "My Fancy App"
}
```

will build the project as `My Fancy App.exe`. The JumpList entry will accordingly be named "My Fancy App".

Now if you wonder how to add more items to `JumpList`, [the official docs have a tutorial for that](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/windows-taskbar).

If you have any more questions or if anything is unclear, I'll gladly help.

Comment: Thanks for that. But how can we change the "my-fancy-app" text into "My Fancy App"?

Comment: In Electron Forge that is done by setting the `productName` property in the `package.json`. Electron Builder will have a similar mechanism

Comment: Actually, it's the same field for Electron Builder, according to their docs. I've updated my answer to include that info